# How to enable visual styles in WPF for common dialogs?

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, styles

When using the wpf elements of my application, everything styles to the operating system, but when I use an OpenDialog or a MessageBox, it renders the older Windows 9X way.  Is there an easier way I can do an Application.EnableVisualStyles() equivalent call to make the message boxes and dialogs look the same as the rest of the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blog post may be worth a look:
[Why does the OpenFileDialog in WPF look so “1999” and how can I fix it?](http://learnwpf.com/post/2007/01/05/Why-does-the-OpenFileDialog-in-WPF-look-so-e2809c1999e2809d-and-how-can-I-fix-it.aspx)

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. The correct one: [link](http://learnwpf.com/post/2007/01/05/Why-does-the-OpenFileDialog-in-WPF-look-so-e2809c1999e2809d-and-how-can-I-fix-it.aspx)

Answer (score 22):

You need to add a manifest to your assembly. You can do this via Add New Item-->General-->Application Manifest file.

Then add the following somewhere inside the asmv1 tag in the manifest file:

```
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" type="win32" processorArchitecture="*" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @NickeManarin Yes, last time I used it on XP, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Im my case in used Winforms controls inside WPF then apply EnableVisualStyles()...

Comment: Winforms is dead and mixing two technologies like Winforms and WPF is neither a recommendable solution nor performant.

Comment: Reminder from the future, more than 10 years later: WinForms still is not dead (don't know whether this is good or bad).